# Integer + 1 and memory

Tags: java, integer

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i = new Integer(400);
        Integer x = i;
        i = i + 1;
        x == i;   
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me to understand the memory's changed about heap and stack. If `x == i` compares memory's address ?

Comment: `x == i` isn't a valid statement, so this code would not compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only line which is not self-explanatory here is:

```
i = i + 1;
```

Because of autoboxing, this line is actually equivalent to:

```
i = Integer.valueOf(i.intValue() + 1);
                      ^ auto-unboxing
            ^ autoboxing
```

So the `intValue` of `i` is moved to the stack; 1 is added; then a new instance of `Integer` may be created on the heap (since values as high as 401 are not guaranteed to be cached by `Integer` internally).

As for `x == i`: assuming you mean something like

```
System.out.println(x == i);
```

That would always print false, since `x` and `i` are different instances.

Comment: Not always, because Integer caching might vary

Answer (score 1):

example: `i` point to address `a1`;
    `x = i` means `x` point to address `a1`;
    `i = i + 1` means x point to address `a2`; 
    so `x == i` will return false as `a1` doesn't equals `a2`.